# Why do the doors between carriages show a no entry sign, yet have to be used by passengers on the Eurotunnel?

Tags: europe, eurotunnel

At the end of each carriage, there are doors that can be opened by pressing a button and waiting for 2 seconds. The picture showing how to use these doors are here:

[image: Photo of door access]

The doors are generally stiff and akward to open. However the bit I'm confusd about is the picture that flashes above the doors:

[Gif of the picture](http://gph.is/2h0IWcF)

It's a no entry sign. It doesn't seem to bare any issues though, as both doors work and can be operated (After the 2 second delay). This random sign just flashes away and doesn't seem to indicate anything. Does anyone know why it's there and what it signifies in this context?

A side note, you have to go through these doors to access the public toilets. These doors are in every carriage, but a toilet could be up to 4 carriages down the train. It seems strange they'd have a no entry sign, yet they'd be asking you to go through the doors to get to the toilet

Comment: Does the sign flash all the time or does it go off when the door opens?

Comment: I believe it's constantly flashing, but would need to double check on my next transit. I remember two ladies pressing the button and even with the sign showing, they could open the door

Comment: Maybe it's analogous to the seat belt sign on an airplane?  It advises you that it's not safe to pass through the door at this time, not even to go to the toilet, but it won't physically prevent you if you insist.

Comment: @NateEldredge Then it should turn off at some point during the journey, but it doesn't. It's flashing during the entire trip and was the same on all the doors I passed on my way to the toilet

Comment: Does the no entry sign continue to flash once you've pressed the button and waited your two seconds? As I recall the two second wait is for adjusting an air-pressure seal to allow passage between carriages, so until that seal is released you can't pass through.

Comment: Given that only the right hand door has a no entry sign, maybe it’s to instruct you to use the left hand door? That appears to have a sign that isn’t illuminated.

Comment: @Notts90 Both doors work equally well, I tried them both. The sign doesn't seem to signify which door you should use

Comment: @ColinMackay It does keep flashing, even if the button is pressed

Comment: I notice in your gif that the sign is flashing.
Clearly this is some kind of an adventure movie type scenario where you have to jump through right as the no entry sign disappears.
(probably a joke)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The illuminated flashing no entry sign usually shows on the 'le shuttle' to indicate that you need to be aware when using them, in particular when the shutters are moving

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M84-0r1OEfc

Or if the motorised split doors are going to move.

https://youtu.be/AwL-0sxAlwU

If you look at the floor in the YouTube videos you will see a marked caution area.

i have not travelled on this train in a while, but seem to remember that whilst the train is in normal motion that the red sign flashes once you push the button for the two seconds whilst the door unlocks, and then the opposite light flashes green for a short moment to indicate that you can plus the doors open

Comment: I've ridden the train again and this time the flashing no entry sign was only on one door out of the available 4. It looks like it was a system glitch causing the last set to constantly flash

Answer (score -8):

This scenario is not at all uncommon.  You will see No Entry/Prohibition signs on many types of trains, including commuter, subway, regional, etc.  Yet, the doors are fully functional and easy to operate.

In these cases, the train operator would really **prefer you not cross** between cars/carriages, especially when the trail is moving, but the doors must remain **accessible for evacuation** purposes.

Comment: And the fact the toilets are in another carrigage, often 3 or 4 carraiges down? There are signs pointing people to go through these doors several times to access toilets, stairs to the other floor, etc.

Comment: @Draken You're way over thinking this.  They don't want people wandering between cars, but it you have to, they're not going to stop you.

Comment: Then why use a no entry sign, which signifies no one should enter without authorisation? There are far better signs that signify danger or other similar things like an exclamation mark in a yellow triangle. A no entry sign and then another sign asking people to go that way to get to the toilets are conflicting signs

Comment: Perhaps it's simply a case that the no entry sign was malfunctioning?

Comment: @Muzer It showed on all doors that I had to wander through to get to the toilet. There are 4 of these doors per carriage, two at either end, and all of them had one sign flashing showing no entry (Both sections of the door still worked as well). I've also seen this on my previous crossing. I doubt it's a fault

Comment: If you want to comment on your answer, like "hey, why are you downvoting" then comment to that effect. Meta talk doesn't belong in your answer.

Comment: @KateGregory Well, no.  But if the rules prevent helping people by pointing out misleading and wrong information, it's not on me.

Comment: @Johns-305 Please do not add "why are you downvoting" to your answer. Add it as a comment if you'd like to discuss with downvoters. Answers should contain only answers and no meta-discussions.

Comment: @JoErNanO  Sure, like I mentioned before, if people are mislead by the unsubstantiated downvotes, it is what it is though I see nothing wrong with defending an otherwise valid Answer.

Comment: "Downvotes without comment are completely wrong and misleading." This answer has five downvotes, The second comment by Draken has five upvotes. I'm willing to guess that most of the people who downvoted (like me) didn't feel the need to post a comment when there are existing comments have already justified the downvote.

Comment: Notice how in [this video](https://youtu.be/MXev0bFA-m8?t=498) the no entry sign isn't visible, even while the shutter doors and passenger doors are opening.

Comment: @Ambo100 Thanks for helping improve the Answer, see edit.  Bit this does demonstrate how downvotes without comment are unhelpful and misleading.

Comment: I'm not sure that's still the case, [you can also see](https://youtu.be/MXev0bFA-m8?t=523) that the light doesn't appear even whilst the train is moving.

Comment: @Ambo100 That's weird, maybe it is a glitch that's been happening recently, everytime I've crossed it's been flashing. Though the trains are starting to deteriorate. So maybe they are just old